# Return File() download does not work in Google Chrome

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Please check the code bellow. I am getting "network error" in Google Chrome browser during download process in progress. Error screen shot attached for better understanding. My goal is give user to download .zip file without knowing file original path (to prevent direct download). But the code bellow works fine for hiding original path just the "network error" is issue. Whats the solution?

Please note I also have tried:

```
return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Zip, fileName);
```

But no luck!

[image: pic]

```
string DownloadableZipFileName = Product.DownloadZipFileName;
    byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Products/Zip/" + DownloadableZipFileName));
    string fileName = "BLEXZ_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + ".zip";
    return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
```

Comment: Google **Chrome** - not "chorome" ....

Comment: haha my bad. If you can plz solve my issue. i am in big problem since long mate.